# Is Betan society secretly sexist?

Tags: vorkosigan-saga

I was reading a reread blog covering the Vorkosigan books. They were discussing some secretive biases and prejudice in Betan society that prevent the people who aren't Cordelia from understanding Vor society and I was suddenly reminded of [this conversation on the Miles to Go forum about whether the fact that the contraceptive implants were limited to women and herms was secretly sexist](http://bar.baen.com/index.php?t=msg&th=91212&start=0&). Unfortunately, the forums require registration, and the discussion is a bit longwinded, so I don't really feel up to posting all of the excerpts, but the main discussion gets into how it's stated several times in the books that, in Betan society, the women and hermaphrodites are the only ones mentioned getting the contraceptive implants. Men, as with our current society, are apparently largely exempt from being responsible for any form of contraception short of a physical barrier or avoiding sex. As with many such discussions, it got a bit charged, and I know that we're probably bringing in our own biases, but it seemed like we came down to two theories.

## It's a matter of authors writing what they know

The first book in the series was written nearly 30 years ago. Society has long emphasized women as the ones responsible for avoiding pregnancy, as they're the ones who'll have to deal with it while the man can always skip town. Even today, in 2014, there really does not exist a reliable form of male contraception that is reversible without surgical intravention. One would expect a futuristic society that can grow children in uterine replicators, clone organs, and even entirely reverse someone's sex to have overcome such barriers, but it's possible that it really is a more difficult problem than we give it credence. Either way, it might have just never been conceivable to Mrs. Bujold that male contraception would become that easy.

## There is an ugly bias at the bottom of Betan egalitarianism

Another possibility, and not even one that's all that unlikely to me, is that the Betan society harbors their own biases which they paper over with their self-image of being an entirely egalitarian society. There's a quote I've run into that first-world countries that they have a tendency to claim to be completely open-minded, but tend to automatically force any person they interact with to conform to their cultural norms. We have hints in *A Civil Campaign* that the Betan Colony has its ugly underside as per [Is Beta Colony less democratic than it seems?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27869/is-beta-colony-less-democratic-than-it-seems).

---

Ultimately, this may not be something that can be answered definitively, unless Mrs. Bujold plans to address it in later books, but I am curious if anyone has seen better evidence within the books of how this is handled.

Comment: "Men, as with our current society, are apparently largely exempt from being responsible for any form of contraception." Are you forgetting the most obvious and ubiquitous form of contraception? I'm sure you're aware of a male-used device that has an effectiveness matched only in female contraception by implanted devices.

Comment: :) Did you miss the rest of the sentence, "short of a physical barrier or avoiding sex"? Although, I realize that I forgot to include the words, "reversible" in there. Yes, vasectomies work very well, but they're pretty permanent.

Comment: I suppose my point is that in our society, there exists significant onus on men to employ contraceptive devices, as they are most easily employed by men. The fact that invasive non-permanent methods were developed for women and not men is not driven by sexism, but rather anatomy.

Comment: Sex is the natural subject to be sexist about.

Comment: No time to write a full answer, but I'll note that the invention of the birth control pill was probably the main thing that made it even remotely *possible* for women to "play" equally with men in the sexual arena. Yes, it affects women more than men, but then so does pregnancy. I guess what I'm trying to get at is that the difference between the sexes on Beta is biological, not cultural.

Comment: It's not sexism, it's biology, specifically _menstruation_. This is what makes female contraceptive implants make perfect sense, while a male version would be nonsensical.

Comment: @JPmiaou Hormonal contraceptives work by preventing *ovulation*, not menstruation (though some may also prevent implantation), which is why some doctors prescribe them to "regulate your cycle." Although men do not have fertility cycles the way women do, it's far from nonsensical to think of a spermicidal implant.

Comment: @MissMonicaE: my point is that female contraceptive implants can have a (highly) desireable side effect that is totally inapplicable to a male version.

Comment: Also, it occurs to me that we may simply not know the whole story: various female characters have described what happens to pubescent female Betans, but none of the male characters have been particularly forthcoming. Maybe there is a corresponding spermicidal implant for men, but they all take it so much for granted that they've forgotten to mention it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a very simple reason why males in Betan (or any other) society don't have contraceptive implants and that is because they cannot conceive. There is a very big difference between birth control in general and a contraceptive implant which stops sperm from fertilizing ova. There's no point in having (and no way to do it) such an implant unless your body is carrying eggs that can be fertilized.

Now, this is not to say that men in any society don't have equal responsibilities with respect to birth control. Of course they do. However, it is true that in mammals (or mammal-like) species, it is the female who carries the eggs and the female who gestates the embryo. While males, at least theoretically, have the option of walking away from their developing offspring as soon as the fun bit is over, females do not. It is therefore even more important for females than for males to control their own bodies and protect themselves against unwanted fertilization. By extension, it seems reasonable that the social norm is that women have the implant. Not because it's a sexist society but because it's the women who will have to bear the brunt of the burden, uterine replicators notwithstanding.

In addition, no matter how advanced your technology is, invasive procedures should always be kept at a minimum. There is no reason to have the entire population reversibly sterilized, you only need to do it to one of the two groups (either the sperm *or* the egg bearers). It makes perfect medical sense to avoid any and all operations unless absolutely necessary. Therefore, Betan society had to choose whether to "sterilize" females or males (herms would get it either way since they carry both sets of apparatus). Since a pregnancy is a much bigger deal to the person in whose body it is actually taking place, it is reasonable to choose that part of the population that has the most to gain by controlling their reproduction: those who actually carry the fetus.

Finally, and perhaps most importantly, sex is not the only way that sperm can be delivered. By ensuring that all who carry a womb also have the implant, other forms of impregnation (forced insemination for example) are also protected against. If it were the males who'd had an equivalent implant, the females could be force impregnated by other means, opening the door to all sorts of horrible crimes. To make a rather mundane analogy, if I want to make sure that no balls enter my hoop, I'd block the hoop, not try and confiscate all balls on campus.

Comment: To further your point, if you want to control births within a colony, you need to ensure that those capable of being impregnated are not impregnated. One unprotected male (visitor perhaps) can theoretically impregnate all unprotected women. But a single unprotected woman only allows for one pregnancy.

Comment: @GorchestopherH exactly. That's the point I was making in my last paragraph.

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether conception needs to happen in the womb: certainly by the time Miles & Ekaterin "start" their twins, it happens entirely in the lab - the embryos go straight from the test tube/petri dish to the uterine replicator. Yes, that's a good 40 years after our introduction to Beta colony, but on the other hand, it's on Barrayar, which is still a bit behind the technology curve.

Comment: @Martha true, but I don't see how it's relevant. Contraception only applies to the traditional method. The betan implant does not stop the bearer from fertilizing their ova _in vitro_, its use is strictly _in vivo_.

Comment: @terdon: Cordelia clearly says that Betan women turn off their implants when they want to conceive, so apparently, the implant *does* stop the bearer from fertilizing their ova *in vitro*. The relevance is mainly as a reply to your "uterine replicators notwithstanding" remark (and the parenthetical that follows it).

Comment: @Martha The fact that they need to get their implants inactivated to conceive does not mean that they conceive _in vitro_. Given the enjoyable nature of the act I doubt any society, no matter how advanced, would forgo intercourse as the main avenue for conception. That said, I just checked my copy of _Diplomatic Immunity_ and you're quire right, M and E started the whole thing in a test tube but the books gives no explanation as to why (at least not in the first few pages). Either way though, the point stands that blocking the receiver rather than the delivery method is a safer approach.

Comment: With contraception + uterine replicators, sex becomes an end in itself; it ceases to have anything to do with reproduction. In my interpretation, Beta Colony *can and does* "forgo intercourse as the main avenue for conception". It's not that they don't have intercourse; it's just that having intercourse has nothing to do with having babies.

Comment: This seems the most reasonable answer. Thank you.

Comment: The new book, *Gentleman Jole and the Red Queen*, confirms my explanation of how uterine replicators work. Basically, for women there's no sex involved whatsoever, and for men, there's sex only insofar as you can label "giving a semen sample" as "sex".

Comment: @Martha fair enough. I'll just remove that bit then. And thanks for letting me know about the new book, I'd missed that!

Comment: Also, the Vor Lord's breeding program in *A Civil Campaign* used ova from women without their knowledge.  This also was a completely sex-free operation.

Comment: On other key detail you missed.  Not all people on Beta Colony are Betans.  if only males were 'steralized' then any time a non-betan visited beta colony he could impregnate a betan female.  Consideirng how sexually fre Betans are it seems their population would be out of control fast with this option.  Choosing females to 'sterilize' prevents this.  By contrast the betans don't really care if a non-betan female gets pregnant from an 'encounter'  with a betan male since it won't affect their population control.  Plus, I don't think we know for certain men don't receive BC implants.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Terdon's statement and it's logic, i would have said the same as part of my answer if not beaten too it.  I just wanted to point out another possible explination.

If you look at this from a meta-level at the time the first books were written IUDs existed and worked, but there  as no known way to give men an implanted birth control.  Thus it makes sense that the author wrote the Beta Colony using the birth control she knew existed but didn't think to write about a form of birth control that at the time didn't exist.   This is no more surprising then the fact that the Vorkosigan Saga has a significant lack of wireless technology because the first world building was done before the previlance of wireless devices.

It's not unreasonable for this logic to actually apply in-universe as well.  From a medical viewpoint It is *far* harder to prevent viable sperm from being produced then it is to prevent conception and implantation of embryos since the later is a vastly more complex process reliant on numerous hormonal triggers of which only one must be stopped to prevent conception.  This is why female implanted birth control existed long before we finally came up with a male version, and why the male version is both less effective at preventing conception and has more severe side effects then the female version today.

We can be confident that both implantation options available to Beta colony surpass the current options.  The degree of side effects, and limited effectiveness, of current IUD technology simply wouldn't be sufficient for the sort of mandatory contraception of Beta Colony.  However, it's quite likely that the female contraceptive implant would still outpace the male equivalent in effectiveness and severity of side effects since it's still the easier medical challenge.  When it came time to mandate at least one side getting implants it would make sense to pick the sex that could use the most effective form of contraceptive, in this case female.  It may very well be that the male contraceptive equivalent was more invasive or still had side effects severe enough that mandating them on males was deemed unjustified compared to the more viable female implant.

Of course this all assumes that males didn't get some form of birth control implants.  Sure we only hear about female implants, but the topic only comes up at times when it affects women.  We can't rule out the possibility that males do have implants and it's just never been brought up.